# What is a complex/difficult example of English tenses?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense, sequence-of-tenses

I'm a native English speaker, and while learning other languages, I've learned that English has more complex tenses than other languages. I don't know what all of the English tenses are, but the most difficult one I can find is the past perfect continuous, i.e. "I had been hoping". But I know I have seen more complex examples before of how confusing tenses can get in English, I suppose by combining multiple tenses into one complex sentence. But I haven't been able to find these examples.

I'm trying to illustrate how complex tenses can become. What are some good example sentences that illustrate the complexity of tenses in English? I'm not looking for realistic sentences, but rather for bizarre examples.

Comment: Modern grammarians tend not to use the term _tense_ to refer to verb constructions such as _had been hoping_. There are plenty of unusual but grammatical verb constructions that are even more complex in the passive voice: _On this day next year the Berlin airport will have been being built for over a decade._

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it assumes a position contrary to that taken to most modern grammarians (that English has just two tenses, present simple and past simple). It's also requesting a list, and assigning the measurable attribute 'craziness' to members of this list. This is the sole domain of nuclear physicists.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's a question, it doesn't "assume a position". Your assertion that "most modern grammarians" (whatever that means) say English has just two tenses is absurd. I live in Europe and interact with English learners daily and the number one thing they comment on is that English tenses are difficult. I am not requesting a "list", I'm requesting (an) example(s) of a sentence with combinations of tenses. Your only remaining objection is that this has something to do with nuclear physics because I used the word craziness?! That is certainly an attribute of something in this discussion.

Comment: See [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/tense-grammar-1692532): 'Many contemporary linguists equate tenses with the inflectional categories of a verb' ... Crystal and Aarts are respected linguists who espouse this analysis. As does John Lawler, often a contributor on ELU. // You are requesting (1) an example of a complicated time-frame-marking construction, and (2) that people should assess it as being the most crazy (or now, complex) type. It's not far off requesting the most oddly spelled word.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, all 16 combinations of the following are possible:

- active or passive voice
- simple or perfective aspect (the latter formed using "have" + past participle)
- simple or progressive aspect (the latter formed using "be" + present participle)
- present or past

So, to speak of a past action which continued until a more recent past event happened: the task **had been being worked on** until something forced it to stop. So that's pluperfect passive progressive. (Pluperfect being another name for past perfect.)

Comment: Middle voice? Shoe's comment?

Comment: Thank you! Maybe something like this is what I was looking for: "If he had lived, he would have been going to have been told that the building will have been being built for over a decade."